# Maintain persistent connection with GCM using perl WWW::Google::Cloud::Messaging

Tags: perl, google-cloud-messaging

I found perl has got a library `WWW::Google::Cloud::Messaging`. I want to maintain a single TCP connection for communicating with GCM rather than opening new connection for individual message. Is this possible using `WWW::Google::Cloud::Messaging`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a persistent connection for GCM type of messaging rather than having a connection opened everytime you make, You can make use of the `libwww` library. Please click on the following [link](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.libwww/1999/11/msg51.html) to download and learn more about the installation.

Hope that Helps!!